# Having issue with Python input

Tags: python, python-3.x, url, user-input, urllib

My `python` code looks like below. Basically, I am joining two part of url using `urljoin` module of `urlib`. The issue that I am facing is during the URL join my output looks like below. As shown below the input from a which is a list is getting displayed at start part of url and end has start information. My expected output is also mentioned below.

To summarize, I want user to input total number of terms and the entered terms should be passed into query part of URL (i.e. query[]=" "&query[]= " "). Not sure if I am missing something.

Thanks in advance for help!

**Code**

```
from urllib.parse import urljoin

num_terms=int(input("Enter total number of search terms:")) #Asking user for number of terms

a=input("Enter all search terms: ").split(",",num_terms) #User enters all the terms

start,end=input("Enter start and end date").split() #User enters start and end date

base_url="http://mytest.org"
join_url="/comments/data?"+"terms[]={}"+"&terms[]={}"*int(num_terms-1)+"&start={}&end={}".format(a,start,end)

url=urljoin(base_url,join_url) #Joining url
url
```

**Output:**

```
Enter total number of search terms:3
Enter all search terms: ty ou io
Enter start and end date2345 7890
"http://mytest.org/comments/data?terms[]={}&terms[]={}&terms[]={}start=['ty ou io']&end=2345"
```

**Expected Output**

```
"http://mytest.org/comments/data?terms[]=ty&terms[]=ou&terms[]=io&start=2345&end=7890"
```

Comment: Are you using this link somewhere in code or you just need to construct one?

Comment: Can you be more clear on your requirement. I see issue with join_url.

Comment: @OlvinRoght...link will be use to make API call and fetch the data....the link provided in question is demo purpose only and resembles to the actual url

Comment: @manjari..correct the issue is with join_url. I would like to get user input for search terms and save those input to the terms part of URL

Comment: Format will start working from "&start={}&end={}".format(a,start,end). So it takes only 2 parameters as there are only 2 {} available. If you want the format to be for entire string then keep entire thing in str(). Your gmformat will work

Comment: @biggboss2019, are you using `requests` for making this api call?

Comment: @OlvinRoght..correct I will use request to make API call

Comment: @biggboss2019, try `requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get", params={"terms[]": ["ty", "ou", "io"], "start": 2345, "end": 7890})` and check what happens ;)

Comment: `input("Enter all search terms: ").split(",",...)` - you are splitting on a comma but your example shows terms separated by spaces.??!

Answer (score 1):

One issue I spotted: the search terms don't have any (,) which you used to split the string.

```
# the base URL path
url_base = "http://mytest.org/comments/data?"

# you don't need a search term number here
# the split below will do the job

# ask for search item directly, must have at least one item
a = input("Enter all search terms (separate by ,): ").split(",")
while len(a) < 1:
    a = input("Enter all search terms (separate by ,): ").split(",")

# ask for the start and end dates, no guarantee they are correct
# so use loop to force the user does the check for you 
dates = input("Enter the start and end date (separate by ,): ").split(",")
while len(dates) != 2:
    dates = input("Enter the start and end date (separate by ,): ").split(",")

# form the URL 
url_search = "&".join([f"terms[]={x}" for x in a])
url_date = "start=" + dates[0] + "&end=" + dates[1]

# the final result
url_final = "&".join([url_base, url_search, url_date])

# print the result
print(url_final)
```

The output is like:

```
Enter all search terms (separate by ,): ty,ou,io
Enter the start and end date (separate by ,): 2000,2022
http://mytest.org/comments/data?&terms[]=ty&terms[]=ou&terms[]=io&start=2000&end=2022
```

Comment: Thank you! Now the only issue is when user enters 1 date it should thow an error . The above date code is running forever

Comment: There were two other issues with the `join_url` assignment in the original code: `a` was not unpacked, and only the last section of the string was being formatted due to a lack of parentheses.

Comment: @biggboss2019 Look into `try-except` statements. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: @biggboss2019 well, in that case you just need to edit the logic of `while len(dates) != 2:` to some error-catching clause

Answer (score 1):

As author mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72902820/10824407#comment128765695_72902820) comment he/she will use `requests` to make an API call, so constructing URL isn't necessary, you can just use functionality of module you're using. You can let `requests` build query string internally by passing `dict` with URL params to `params` argument *(read [Passing Parameters In URLs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls))*:

```py
import requests

response = requests.get(
    "http://mytest.org/comments/data",
    {
        "terms[]": ["ty", "ou", "io"],
        "start": 2345,
        "end": 7890
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple **`for` loop** should suffice:

```py
terms = ""
for i in range(num_terms):
    terms += f"terms[]={a[i]}&"
```

Basically, `format` takes a single value, it does not iterate over a list as you wanted. This is a simple way to achieve your goal. You could probably use list comprehension as well.

```py
[f"terms[]={term}"for term in a]
```

##### Output:

```
Enter total number of search terms:3
Enter all search terms: au,io,ua
Enter start and end date233 444
http://mytest.org/comments/data?terms[]=au&terms[]=io&terms[]=ua&&start=233&end=444
```

Comment: Receiving list index out of range error.  I am doing something like this after start,end line of the code ->                                                                             terms = ""
for i in range(num_terms):
    terms += f"terms[]={a[i]}&"


base_url="http://mytest.org"
join_url=("/comments/data?"+terms+f"&start={start}&end={end}")

url=urljoin(base_url,join_url) #Joining url
url

Comment: If you are using your example input, then the problem is quite simply that you are giving the wrong input. Instead of `ty ou io`, input `ty,ou,io`. That will work since you are using a comma as the delimiter in `split`

Answer (score 0):

One problem is your code is only formatting the last bit of the url. That is,

```py
"&start={}&end={}".format(a,start,end)
```

is the only part where the formatting applies; you need to add parentheses.

The other thing is that we need to [unpack](https://realpython.com/lessons/tuple-assignment-packing-unpacking/) the list of terms, `a`, in the `.format` function:

```py
join_url=("/comments/data?"+"terms[]={}"+"&terms[]={}"*int(num_terms-1)+"&start={}&end={}").format(*a,start,end)
```

But I'd recommend using `f-strings` instead of `.format`:

```py
join_url=("/comments/data?"+'&'.join([f"terms[]={term}"for term in a])+f"&start={start}&end={end}")
```

(I also used `str.join` for the terms instead of string multiplication.)

Comment: HI Bob, output is getting displayed as 'http://mytest.org/comments/data?terms[]=as we ty&start=123&end=567'. The expected output will be 'http://mytest.org/comments/data?terms[]=as &terms[]=we&terms[]= ty&start=123&end=567'

Comment: biggboss2019 That's because your code splits at the `,` character, not a space. I made the same mistake while testing your code, you may want to change that